# Error Calling Console App from Web Form

Tags: asp.net, debugging, console, console-application

This is related to another question I asked:

[ProcessStartInfo Multiple Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054178/processstartinfo-multiple-arguments)

I got this working with no errors in Windows Logs when run from the command line. Basically, I'm calling the console application from a Web Form. I'm passing two string arguments: an email subject and an email body. The console application then sends an email to a drop folder (for now).

```
const string MAILER_FILEPATH = @"C:\VS2010\Mailer\bin\Debug\Mailer.exe";

ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();

string arguments = String.Format(@"""{0}"" ""{1}""", 
    message.Subject.Replace(@"""", @""""""), 
    message.Body.Replace(@"""", @""""""));             
info.FileName = MAILER_FILEPATH;

Process process = Process.Start(info.FileName, arguments);
Process.Start(info);
```

When I call the console app from the Web Form, it still created the email in the drop folder but also generates two consecutive errors in the Windows Application Log:

**Error 1:**

> Application: Mailer.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
>   The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
>   Info: System.IndexOutOfRangeException Stack: at
>   Mailer.Mailer.Main(System.String[])

---

**Error 2:**

> Faulting application name: Mailer.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp:
>   0x4ebab7ad Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e21213c Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x000000000000cacd Faulting process id: 0x1648 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01cc9f079d89d950 Faulting application path:
>   C:\VS2010\Mailer\bin\Release\Mailer.exe Faulting module path:
>   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   dbf249c0-0afa-11e1-a04b-a4badb02debf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by enclosing my console code with:

```
if (args.Length >= 0)
{

}
```

By changing this to >=1, the no more errors were logged!