# How to run cmd.exe using c# with multiple arguments?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following code to open the .exe and then I would like to pass another argument to it:

```
ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
StartInfo.Arguments = @"/k set inetroot=c:\depot&set corextbranch=surfacert_v2_blue_kit&c:\depot\tools\path1st\myenv.cmd";
Process.Start(StartInfo);`
```

Which opens up the window as below.
[image]

Now I also need to pass "sd sync dirs" which gives me some result and would like to capture the result to a variable.[image]

To accomplish this I need to pass two agruments in the 
ProcessStartInfo.Arguments.
How can I add this second argument in the above code to take care of everything in C# code.

Comment: `StartInfo.Arguments += " /another-argument"` perhaps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass multiples arguments in processStartInfo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061854/how-to-pass-multiples-arguments-in-processstartinfo)

Answer (score 1):

Since its just a string try this:

```
string[] MyArguments = { "firstarg", "secondarg"};
Process.Start("cmd.exe", String.Join(" ", MyArguments));
```

Where firstarg and secondarg are your arguments.

EDIT:
Oops forgot to tell you ,if your argument contains spaces do this(the example contains 1 argument with spaces-first arg- and 1 without spaces-secondarg):

```
string[] MyArguments = { "\"first arg\"", "secondarg" };
```

Comment: Tried but looks like it is not taking the seconde argument. I still see the window as it is shown is the first picture, after running the code.

Comment: edited...forgot to tell you sorry,so if your arguments both have spaces do like in first arg example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of passing multiple arguments:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfbyhds5.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx

If you're passing strings you need to take account of the possibility of quotes being included in the subject line or body text. I enlisted some help on this issue with a StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054178/processstartinfo-multiple-arguments).

I ended up with something like this:

```
// DOS command line
C:\>ConsoleApplication1 "Subject Line Text" "Some body text"

// Web form code-behind
// Pass subject and message strings as params to console app    
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();

string arguments = String.Format(@"""{0}"" ""{1}""",
     subjectText.Text.Replace(@"""", @""""""),
     messageText.Text.Replace(@"""", @""""""));
     info.FileName = MAILER_FILEPATH;

Process process = Process.Start(info.FileName, arguments);
Process.Start(info);

// Console application
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length >= 2)
    {
        // Do stuff 
    }
}
```